# Getting Value of A String by $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have a form, getting values by `$_POST`according to `name` that's okay. But how can I get value of not input. For example;

```
<b name="name1" value="1001">Phones</b>
```

How can I get 1001 by `$_POST` according to `name="name1"`. Trying `$_POST['name1']` but can't get.

Comment: the `<b>` tag is not considered as an (POST/form) input; that's why.

Comment: you cannot get by $_POST, you have to use jquery/js to get this value.

Comment: Hi friend <b> tag is a not a form tag so you can not get <b> tag value in $_POST after submit but using jquery or make hidden variable for the <b> tag value and to display purpose push value in b tag and also add in hidden text box

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I got it thanks to David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have isn't a form input:

```
<b name="name1" value="1001">Phones</b>
```

The *entire HTML* isn't sent to the server in a form post, only form values are.  So you need to have that in a form input.  For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="1001" />
```

Then you don't need that information in your `<b>` element:

```
<b>Phones</b>
```

Comment: Aww okay. I understood now.